# To know the sass structure

Tags: sass

This is my sass structure please explain what does its mean?

actually am analysing a code structure. am unable to understad the structure.

```
.class-name{
  some styles..
  &.class-name2{
    some styles..
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you do search in Google? Or look up the [documentation for Sass](http://sass-lang.com/guide)?

Comment: What part do you not understand? Do you understand CSS? Documentation is a good place to start. You also could also run the sass task and take a look at output (css). The code shows 'Nesting' and uses 'Referencing Parent Selectors with &'

Comment: Thank you.. sure i need to go deep into the documentation.

Comment: Another way is to render the scss to a browser and review the resulting css code. You can run scss locally using git + ruby sass gem, but there are other ways to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The `&` tells the pre-processor to add the parent selector in-front of the nested class.

so this:

```
.class-name{
      background: blue
      &.class-name2{
          background: red;
      }
}
```

would compile too:

```
.class-name {background: blue;}
.class-name.class-name2 {background: red;}
```

The usage would be:

```
<div class="class-name">This background is blue</div>
```

and

```
<div class="class-name class-name2">This background is red</div>
```

Comment: Woww.. really thank you for the answer..!!!